# How to sanitize log messages in Log4j to save them in database

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j

I'm trying to save log messages to a central database. In order to do this, I configured the following Appender in log4j's xml configuration:

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
            <param name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/logging_test" />
            <param name="user" value="test_user" />
            <param name="password" value="test_password" />
            <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO log_messages ( log_level, message, log_date ) VALUES ( '%p', '%m', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' )" />
</appender>
```

This works fine, except some of the messages contain ', and then the appender fails.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this non official [Log4J JDBCAppender](http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/index.html) which fixes this issue and is distributed under the Apache 2.0 license. Quoting its features in comparision to `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`:

> - Log to (relational) database
> - Flexible connection handling (does not yet support DataSource)
> - Flexible sql commands to execute actual logging
> - Prepared Statements and Stored Procedures (J2SDK 1.4+) supported
> - Enables logging of messages with special characters such as ' (single
>     quote) and , (comma)
> - Flexible table and column structure
> - Flexible id generation
> - Multiple PatternLayout applications allowed; in one or more
>     columns
> - Supports J2SDK 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5
> - Supports Log4j 1.2.9 and current development

Or, and you should seriously consider this option, switch from log4j to its successor, [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) (this is where things happen) which has a [`DBAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html) that uses `PreparedStatement` (see the [sources](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html)), that can use a JNDI datasource, connection pooling (this is a big plus), etc. For more information about this appender, refer to the online manual http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender

Comment: An alternative library is one possible solution, but doesn't answer the question of how to sanitize the data while using `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest creating a custom appender and overriding the `flushBuffer` and `execute` methods where you can escape your strings or use `PreparedStatement` :

```
public class MyJDBCAppender extends JDBCAppender {

}
```

To explain why you need to override `flushBuffer` - the appender puts `LogEvent` objects into a buffer which is later flushed towards the target (database in this case). Here, the `flushBuffer` method uses `getLogStatement` and (via `execute`) a normal `Statement`. You can replace that behaviour completely. Have a look a [the current source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.java.html)

Then register your appender istead of `JDBCAppender`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with log4j or JDBC, but I do know JDBC supports prepared statements. Perhaps there is a way to use that with the JDBCAppender

Comment: You can extend the JDBCAdapter to work with prepared statements if it does not have an option to use them already. Extending it should be relatively simple

Answer (score 3):

i solved the thing in the following way :

Copied the source code of the `JDBCAppender` called `ACMEJDBCAppender`

override the `getLogStatement(LoggingEvent event)` method, cloning the old event and providing the new one with the escaped message.

Not the cleanest solution from the oop point of view but it does the work. Hope it helps.

```
protected String getLogStatement(LoggingEvent event) {

  LoggingEvent clone = new LoggingEvent(
    event.fqnOfCategoryClass,
    LogManager.getLogger(event.getLoggerName()),
    event.getLevel(),
    AidaUtils.sqlEscape(event.getMessage().toString()),
    event.getThrowableInformation()!=null ? event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable() : null
  );

  return getLayout().format(clone);
}
```

Comment: Was ok to extend JDBCAppender and override this method. Clean and fast. Thx

Comment: Did you forget to add event.getTimeStamp() to cloned event or is intentional?.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Javadocs](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html), the offical JDBCAppender is quite limited, and in particular has no good way of dealing with this issue.

One way around it is to use an alternative appender, such as [this one](http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/index.html) which aims to be functionally compatible with the Log4J one except, you know, work.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem logging to Oracle, you can use Oracle's quote operator.

Wrap the quote operator around %m (i.e. q#'%m'#)

For example:

```
INSERT INTO log_messages ( log_level, message, log_date ) 
VALUES ( '%p', q#'%m'#, '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Joao, sorry for being late, but here it is:

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.db.DBAppender">                                                                                                             
                <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">                                                                                       
                        <param name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />                                                                                                 
                        <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database" />                                                                                      
                        <param name="user" value="user" />                                                                                                                          
                        <param name="password" value="password" />                                                                                                                 
                </connectionSource>                                                                                                                                                
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">                                                                                                                    
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %c - %m%n" />                                                                                          
                </layout>                                                                                                                                                          
        </appender>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server you can use the following

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
INSERT INTO log_messages ( log_level, message, log_date ) VALUES ( "%p", ":%m", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" )'
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
```

Which shifts the problem to double quotes.  If you don't have double quotes in your messages this could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For postgresql, use $$

Example: $$%m$$