# How can I get the hql query from a grails transaction?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

We have a grails application with a legacy database.  When a user logs into our app and does transactions we need to keep track of the sql that is occurring during the session.  From a code standpoint is there a way to get the hql being ran when a .save() is called and translate this into sql?  I have seen where you can turn on the logging for it but I would rather not try and parse this info out of the log files during runtime.

Comment: Maybe you want something like [save log in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214140/configuring-log4j-property-file-to-store-in-mysql-database)?

Comment: If your updates are all through Grails application you can use [Audit Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging). This will not give you the sql but it will track every insert/update/delete

Comment: @Alidad thank you for the information, does this put it in a log file? or can I grab it runtime and do what I please with it?

Comment: @southpaul It will store it in a table and you can access it anytime, It also give you a basic report if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 : You can log the sql by setting the below property in log4j.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Approach 2:

You also can provide comments to SQL output.
The Query interface has a setComment() method that takes a String object as an argument:

```
public Query setComment(String comment)
```

Use this to identify the SQL output in your application logs, if SQL logging is enabled.
for instance

```
String hql = "from Supplier";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setComment("My HQL: " + hql);
List results = query.list();
```

The output in your log will have the comment in a Java-style comment before the SQL:

Hibernate: /*My HQL: from Supplier*/ select supplier0_.id as id, supplier0_.name вћҐ as name2_ from Supplier supplier0_

Here is the link that explains how to store Logs into DB.   [How to sanitize log messages in Log4j to save them in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042070/how-to-sanitize-log-messages-in-log4j-to-save-them-in-database)

Comment: Is there any way to have this same functionality but not have it go to a log file?  I need to access this runtime without parsing log files.

Comment: To take this a step further, extend an appender in log4j and make it push to a DB or jms queue or whatever...

Comment: As per DAJ suggestion, here is the link that explains how to store Logs into DB.