# Logging into Database with Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm logging my application's logs into database using JDBCAppender of log4j.
At some point, I get "MySQLSyntaxErrorException" and I'm trying to find out the cause.

Here is my log4j.properties file;

```
# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://.../...
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=...
log4j.appender.DB.password=...
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO logs (EventDate,Level,Logger,Location,Message) VALUES( '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}', '%p' , '%c' ,'Test', '%m')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

And here is my table;

[image]

When I run my project I'm getting following error;

> *log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.*

If I change '%m' parameter with anything else, no exception occurs and log is inserted into DB successfully. So, I think the problem is with the message itself here but I cannot find out which message is causing it since it's a real huge project.

Is there any way that I can see the actual SQL statement?
Or is there anything else that I can do to debug this more?

Comment: Can it be that you have an single qoute in your message? Which lead to a syntax error because it is not escaped?

Comment: @Jens This is what I'm thinking but I can't really find it anywhere. This is why I'm trying to find a way to see the insert statement. Or, is it possible to handle it(escape) inside my log4j.properties maybe?

Comment: I think the right way is to set the column mapping https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/appenders.html and not a SQL query

Comment: or read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042070/how-to-sanitize-log-messages-in-log4j-to-save-them-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could occur when the log message `%m` itself contains `'` character.
Did you try to replace `'`

```
INSERT INTO logs (EventDate,Level,Logger,Location,Message) VALUES( 'date_here', 'INFO' , 'com.test.Test' ,'loc', REPLACE('%m','\'','') );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your point made me understand it better and solve the problem with similar approach. REPLACE("%m","\'","") is working!

Comment: great! glad you figure it out